# HTML full size div containing a draggable table

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

I'm not sure how to explain what I exactly want (which makes it really hard to google for as well), but I would like to create a table with each cell a specific width and height (let's say 40x40 pixels).

This table will be way larger than the viewport, so it would need some scrolling, but I don't want scrollbars (this part ain't a problem), but a way to drag the table around "behind the viewport".

To make it a bit more complex, I need to be able to center a specific cell and know which cell is centered too (although if I know for example that the table is on left: -520px; I can calculate what the situation is).

Long story short, I'm looking for something that looks and works like maps.google.com, but then with a table and cells instead of a canvas or divs.

Comment: Without sample code we won't help.

Comment: I understand, but there is not really a code sample as there is no code. I'm trying to find a concept that could work, then I'll write the code (I'm not expecting someone to write my any code). I just have no clue where to start.

Comment: I think this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. Normally you have to try something on your own and ask a specific question when you are stuck...

Comment: I was a bit afraid for that when I posted the question. I have tried a dozen things with div overflows etc., but it all doesn't work and I was just hoping that I wasn't the first one stuck with this concept, or someone thought of something really simple I didn't see because I'm stuck in the same circle for days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is relatively simple. You have a container `div` element with `position: relative; overflow: hidden` applied via CSS and the content set to `position: absolute`. For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-grid">
        ... your grid HTML ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

You then need to set up some mouse/touch tracking javascript, you can find plenty of examples around Stack Overflow or Google, which monitors the position of the mouse at `mousedown` or `touchstart` events and then tests this repeatedly on an interval to see where the pointer is and update the `content-grid` top and left position, until `mouseup` or `touchend`.

You can make this animation smooth using CSS transition on left and top.

The tricky bit is calculating the position for the centre cell. For this I would recommend calculating a central zone, the size of your grid cells (i.e. 40x40) in the middle of your container element. Then checking if any grid cell is currently more than 1/4 inside that zone, and treating it as the "central" element.

Here is a basic example for position a cell within a grid within a wrapper: https://jsfiddle.net/tawt430e/1/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit disappointed to see the down votes of my question at first. I can imagine that stackoverflow has a lot of issues with new people just trying to get their code written here, but that's not what I asked.

Anyway, with the "you share the problem, you share the solution", mindset, I fixed the code with help of tw_hoff and it all works now. It even saves the coordinates in the local storage so this example HTML keeps you in the same position if you refresh the page. I added the two example images I used as well (store the left one as farm.png, the right one as tile.png, same directory as the html page).

[image: farm.png][image: tile.png]

The actual code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Game map demo</title>
  <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: darkgreen;">
    <div id="content" style="white-space: nowrap;">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            var tile;

            if((i == 4 || i == 5) && (j == 2 || j == 3)) {
                tile = 'farm';
            } else {
                tile = 'tile';
            }

            $("#content").append('<div style="background: url(\'' + tile + '.png\'); width: 128px; height: 128px; position: absolute; margin-left: ' + (i * 128) + 'px; margin-top: ' + (j * 128) + 'px;"></div>');
        }
    }

    $("body").css("-webkit-user-select","none");
    $("body").css("-moz-user-select","none");
    $("body").css("-ms-user-select","none");
    $("body").css("-o-user-select","none");
    $("body").css("user-select","none");

    var down = false;
    var current_left = 0;
    var current_top = 0;

    if(localStorage.getItem("current_left") && localStorage.getItem("current_top")) {
        current_left = Number(localStorage.getItem("current_left"));
        current_top = Number(localStorage.getItem("current_top"));

        console.log(current_left);

        $("#content").css('marginLeft', (current_left) + 'px');
        $("#content").css('marginTop', (current_top) + 'px');
    }

    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        down = true;
    }).mouseup(function() {
        down = false;  
    });

    var cache_pageX;
    var cache_pageY;

    $( "#map" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
        if(down == true) {
            current_left += (-1 * (cache_pageX - event.pageX));
            if(current_left > 0)
                current_left = 0;

            if(current_left < (-2560 + $("#map").width()))
                current_left = (-2560 + $("#map").width());

            current_top += (-1 * (cache_pageY - event.pageY));
            if(current_top > 0)
                current_top = 0;

            if(current_top < (-2560 + $("#map").height()))
                current_top = (-2560 + $("#map").height());

            localStorage.setItem("current_left", current_left);
            localStorage.setItem("current_top", current_top);

            $("#content").css('marginLeft', (current_left) + 'px');
            $("#content").css('marginTop', (current_top) + 'px');
        }

        cache_pageX = event.pageX;
        cache_pageY = event.pageY;
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It still needs some work, and of course a lot of work to be actually used in a game, but this part works and I hope if someone else ever might have the same issue and searches for it on stackoverflow my solutions gives them a push in the right direction :).

Thanks for those that helped!